# How to use .sys driver functions in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a specific driver(a firewall driver) which i managed to load with delphi but i dont know how to call his function inside my program.
The specification for this functions on driver are like folows :
Firewall functions can be called with DeviceIoControl (DDoSflt) 
    IoControl codes (needed for DeviceIoControl) are as following:

```
0x2220c0 = IOCTL_START
Input:  none
Output: none
```

After loading the driver, call this function to install firewall hook.

```
0x2220c4 = IOCTL_STOP
Input:  none
Output: none
```

Call this function to disable the firewall without unloading it.

```
0x2220c8 = IOCTL_DDOSADDIP
Input:  a DWORD containing an IP address
Output: none
```

This function notifies the firewall that a DDoS attack is in progress and adds an IP to DDoS filter. Until IOCTL_DDOSSTOP is called, all the traffic from IPs that are in DDoS filter will be filtered.

```
0x2220cc = IOCTL_DDOSSTOP
Input:  none
Output: none
```

This function notifies the firewall that DDoS attack was stopped, the function will delete the DDoS filter.

```
0x2220d0 = IOCTL_BAN0
Input:  two DWORDs containing an IP range
Output: none
```

This function sets a ban on an IP range.

```
0x2220d4 = IOCTL_GETFLT
Input:  none
Output: DWORD
```

This function returns the number of filtered TCP/SYN packets that were sent from IPs found in DDoS filter.
2. Structures used by firewall

2.1. FirewallParametersInfo

```
typedef struct _FirewallParametersInfo{
    WORD    pcapFlags;  // bit 0 = WinPCap is enabled, bit 1 = detection of adapters was completed (this WORD is not used by version 1.03 of DDoSflt)
    WORD    pcapAdapters;   // mask of enabled / disabled adapters used by WinPCap procedures (this WORD is not used by version 1.03 of DDoSflt)
    DWORD   pcapTimer;  // timeout for capturing packets using WinPCap procedures (not used by version 1.03 of DDoSflt)
    BYTE    pcapSyn;    // maximum number of TCP/SYN packets per second allowed from one IP
    BYTE    pcapUdp;    // maximum number of UDP packets per second allowed from one IP
    BYTE    pcapIcmp;   // maximum number of ICMP packets per second allowed from one IP
    BYTE    firewallFlags;  // bit 0 = firewall is registered
                // bit 1 = firewall is started
                // bit 2 = maximum SYN/second on hub's registered ports will be checked
                // bit 3 = maximum SYN/second on unregistered ports will be checked
                // bit 4 = ICMP traffic will be blocked
                // bit 5 = TCP/RST packets will not be sent (will be filtered)
                // bit 6 = if flood is detected, the application will call the firewall to set a _ban0_ (not used by firewall)
                // bit 7 = if flood is detected, a notification message will be sent in opchat (not used by firewall)
    WORD    hubSyn;     // maximum SYN rate allowed for one of registered hub's ports
    WORD    otherSyn;   // maximum SYN rate allowed for non-registered ports
} FirewallParametersInfo;
```

2.2. port_info

```
typedef struct _port_info{
    WORD    port;       // port value in network byte order
    int synRate;    // maximum number of TCP/SYN packets per second allowed from all users
} port_info;
```

---

This is ...

Comment: Have you read the documentation for DeviceIoControl yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a handle to the driver using CreateFile API then you will be able to send commands to the driver using DeviceIoControl.

```
    function InstallAndStartDriver(DriverPath,DriverName: WideString; out DriverDevice : THandle): Boolean;
    var
      hSCManager, hService: THandle;
      lpServiceArgVectors: PWideChar;
    begin
      Result := False;
      hSCManager := 0;
      hSCManager := OpenSCManagerW(nil, nil, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
      if hSCManager <> 0 then
      begin
        try
          hService := 0;
          hService := CreateServiceW(hSCManager, DriverName, DriverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, PWideChar(DriverPath), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil);
          hService := 0;
          lpServiceArgVectors := nil;
          hService := OpenServiceW(hSCManager, DriverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
          if hService <> 0 then
          begin
            try
              if StartServiceW(hService, 0, PWideChar(lpServiceArgVectors)) then
              begin
                Result := True;
              end;
            finally
              CloseServiceHandle(hService);
            end;
          end;
        finally
          CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        end;
      end;
      if Result then
      begin
      DriverDevice := CreateFileW(PWideChar('\\.\' + DriverName), GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR(nil), OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
      Result := GetLastError() = ERROR_SUCCESS;
      end;
    end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  driver : THandle;
begin
  if InstallAndStartDriver('D:\mydriver.sys','Firewall',driver) then
    DeviceIoControl(...)
end;
```

Comment: I m stuck already cause i dont know how to get the handle of the driver.Never used sys in my programs before and it seems documentation is very low in delphi.

Comment: `h:=CreateFile(
             { lpFileName: PChar            } '\\.\'+ DEVICE_NAME_STRING,
             { dwDesiredAccess: integer     } GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,
             { dwShareMode: Integer         } 0,
             { lpSecurityAttributes         } PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR(nil),
             { dwCreationDisposition: DWORD } OPEN_EXISTING,
             { dwFlagsAndAttributes: DWORD  } FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
             { hTemplateFile: THandle       } 0);
  if h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  Begin
   showmessage('R invalid handle');
   // dwStatus := GetLastError();
  end;`

Comment: @user Don't look for documentation and example code in Delphi. Learn to read C examples.

Comment: David , i loaded driver , i installed him , i started him..driver was shown by driver view program...The only problem i got stuck is how to load those functions and got message from sys back to my progr.i used this to send but sometimes i got bsod : DeviceIoControl(h,$2220c0,nil,0,nil,0,r,nil);//if? this is for 0x2220c0 = IOCTL_START functions of driver
 CloseHandle(h);

Comment: If you get BSOD then perhaps you are sending the wrong commands to the driver. Or perhaps the driver has a bug. Please don't post code in comments. It is not readable. As for how to proceed, I would start by trying to translate the C examples for your driver. You should also make sure that you can compile and run those C examples so that you can compare the C and Delphi versions, specifically the parameters that you are sending.

Comment: @user1468506 try this code if it still fails maybe there is a problem with the driver.

Comment: Thanks that code it is working nice, i already installed and started driver with GWIOPM framework.The problem are functions dont know if i call them corectly ex :DeviceIoControl(h,$2220cc,nil,0,nil,0,r,nil); for 0x2220cc = IOCTL_DDOSSTOP
 Input: none
 Output: none

Comment: yes it comes with asm code, its not my driver i only try to reimplement it in a delphi program . If you want the code send me a mail at buzzbuzzu@gmail.com

Comment: The sample code that calls `DeviceIoControl` is written in assembler? Really?

Comment: nope David , the driver is written in asm.The code i develop is big to post here.Send me a mail and i will send you full source code if you want to look at it

Comment: actually the code i use for DeviceIoControl :DeviceIoControl(hDevice,x,nil,0,nil,0,result,nil);         (where x is a cardinal value)

Comment: Does the driver come with any sample code that calls `DeviceIoControl`? If not then you should ask the vendor to supply such sample code.